# HTML and CSS button positioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 4 buttons on this HTML page, currently they are all in a straight line going down the middle. I would like to have one button (the master button) be in the top middle than below have the other 3 buttons going horizontally.Thank you for any help.This is what the HTML looks like(button 7 is the master)...

```
<body>
    <section>
        <a href="#" value="Off" onclick="button7()" id="button7">&#xF011;</a>
        <span></span>
    </section>
    <section>
        <a href="#" value="Off" onclick="button1()" id="button1">&#xF011;</a>
        <span></span>
    </section>
    <section>
        <a href="#" value="Off" onclick="button2()" id="button2">&#xF011;</a>
        <span></span>
    </section>
    <section>
        <a href="#" value="Off" onclick="button3()" id="button3">&#xF011;</a>
        <span></span>
    </section>
</body>
```

Than there is the CSS...

```
body {
    background: url('http://subtlepatterns.com/patterns/micro_carbon.png');
}
section {
    margin: 150px auto 0;
    width: 75px;
    height: 95px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
:active, :focus {
    outline: 0;
}
/** Font-Face **/
@font-face {
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  src: url("fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot");
  src: url("fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix") format('eot'), 
       url("fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff") format('woff'), 
       url("fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf") format('truetype'), 
       url("fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg#FontAwesome") format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
/** Styling the Button **/
a {
    font-family: "FontAwesome";
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(250,250,250,0.1);
    font-size: 32pt;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 0px 0px rgb(34,34,34),
                0px 7px 10px 0px rgb(17,17,17),
                inset 0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(250, 250, 250, .2), 
                inset 0px -12px 35px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    border: 0;
    color: rgb(37,37,37);
    border-radius: 35px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 79px;
    background-color: rgb(83,87,93);

    transition: color 350ms ease, text-shadow 350ms;
        -o-transition: color 350ms ease, text-shadow 350ms;
        -moz-transition: color 350ms ease, text-shadow 350ms;
        -webkit-transition: color 350ms ease, text-shadow 350ms;
}
a:before {
    content: "";
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    display: block;
    z-index: -2;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgb(26,27,29);
    left: -5px;
    top: -2px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(250,250,250,0.1), 
                inset 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
a:active {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px rgb(34,34,34),
                0px 3px 7px 0px rgb(17,17,17),
                inset 0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(250, 250, 250, .2), 
                inset 0px -10px 35px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    background-color: rgb(83,87,93);
    top: 3px;
}
a.on {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px rgb(34,34,34),
                0px 3px 7px 0px rgb(17,17,17), 
                inset 0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(250, 250, 250, .2), 
                inset 0px -10px 35px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    background-color: rgb(83,87,93);
    top: 3px;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgb(250,250,250);
}
a:active:before, a.on:before {
    top: -5px;
    background-color: rgb(26,27,29);
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(250,250,250,0.1), 
                inset 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
/* Styling the Indicator light */
a + span {
    display: block;
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    background-color: rgb(226,0,0);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(250,250,250,0.5),
                0px 0px 3px 2px rgba(226,0,0,0.5);
    border-radius: 4px;
    clear: both;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 42%;
    transition: background-color 350ms, box-shadow 700ms;
    -o-transition: background-color 350ms, box-shadow 700ms;
    -moz-transition: background-color 350ms, box-shadow 700ms;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 350ms, box-shadow 700ms;
}
a.on + span {
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(250,250,250,0.5),
                0px 0px 3px 2px rgba(135,187,83,0.5);
    background-color: rgb(135,187,83);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified your html code, i dont have reputation to comment, so posting as answer.
Not sure is this what you need ?

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rahulsambari/LE3QS/)

```
  <body >
    <section style="margin:0 0 0 50%">
        <a href="#" value="Off" onclick="button7()" id="button7">&#xF011;</a>
        <span></span>
    </section>
<div style="margin:0 0 0 48%">
    <section style="float:left">
        <a href="#" value="Off" onclick="button1()" id="button1">&#xF011;</a>
        <span></span>
    </section>
    <section style="float:left">
        <a href="#" value="Off" onclick="button2()" id="button2">&#xF011;</a>
        <span></span>
    </section>
    <section style="float:left">
        <a href="#" value="Off" onclick="button3()" id="button3">&#xF011;</a>
        <span></span>
    </section>
    </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: You should use the HTML `style` attribute as little as possible. Use CSS instead for style.

Comment: you want it in middle ?

Comment: Thank you for your efforts, it is still not aligned right.

Comment: just modify `48%` of `<div style="margin:0 0 0 48%">` to `47%` and try... i guess it should do

Comment: can you just post your code here..?, if not i can tell you how to do it

Comment: It's the same as above

Comment: try modifying `<div style="margin:0 0 0 48%">` to `<div style="margin:0px 0 0 48%">` and `<section style="margin:0 0 0 50%">` to `<section style="margin:0 0 0px 50%">`

Comment: that did not do anything

Comment: try adding `padding:0` in every button's `<section>` and `<div>` along with our `margin` like `<div style="margin:0 0 0 48%; padding:0">`

Comment: hehe ..anytime. But you can zero down your search to making `margin` and `padding` to 0 or very less to reduce the distance between them.

Answer (score 0):

`float:left;` on the bottom 3. `clear:left;` on the 2nd (meaning the 1st of the bottom 3).
If you want to center the bottom 3, wrap in a div, give the div a width and height then `margin:0 auto;` on the div, then you don't have to `clear:left;`.

Note `section` is not backward compatible with IE 7.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the last 3 in a DIV and set these styles: **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/XnaY2/)**

CSS:

```
body div section { float: left; }
body div { margin: 0 auto; overflow: hidden; width: 225px; }
```

HTML:

```
   <section>
        <a href="#" id="button7">&#xF011;</a><span></span>
    </section>
<div>
    <section>
        <a href="#" id="button1">&#xF011;</a><span></span>
    </section>
    <section>
        <a href="#" id="button2">&#xF011;</a><span></span>
    </section>
    <section>
        <a href="#" id="button3">&#xF011;</a><span></span>
    </section>
</div>
```

*I simplifed the  tags to save space and make it more readable*

Comment: This worked very well for the most part thank you, only problem is the button to the far left is cut off a little bit, along with the led's at the bottom of the buttons

Comment: @user3808597, you may need to play around with the width and height css for the container div or try taking off the `overflow:hidden;`

Answer (score 0):

If I read your question right, you need to do the following:

In your css, add:

```
#wrap {
            width:100%;
            display:inline-flex;
    }

    #wrap:after {
            content: ".";
            display: block;
            height: 0;
            clear: both;
            visibility: hidden;
            display: inline-flex;
            flex-direction: row;    
    }
```

and then between the second button add a div with an id of wrap

```
<div id="wrap">
```

Then end your div after the last `</section>` tag

This gives you your top button on the top line, and the 3 remaining on the line below, centered on the page.

Amended code:

```
<body>
    <section>
        <a href="#" value="Off" onclick="button7()" id="button7">&#xF011;</a>
        <span></span>
    </section>
    <div id="wrap">
    <section>
        <a href="#" value="Off" onclick="button1()" id="button1">&#xF011;</a>
        <span></span>
    </section>
    <section>
        <a href="#" value="Off" onclick="button2()" id="button2">&#xF011;</a>
        <span></span>
    </section>
    <section>
        <a href="#" value="Off" onclick="button3()" id="button3">&#xF011;</a>
        <span></span>
    </section>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change your HTML, you can use the following styles in addition to what you have posted:

```
body {
    text-align: center;
}
section:first-child ~ section {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ryanwheale/ML7sK/

I recommend using a wrapping div with a class like "buttons" and using that in your styles:

```
.buttons {
    text-align: center;
}
.buttons > section:first-child ~ section {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ryanwheale/ML7sK/1/